# Can't Perform an event inside a Collider OnCollisionEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject which when picked up and collides with a certain collider(detect) then it should drop the object and proceed to perform a specific event (Pouring a liquid) inside the collider.

The problem i have is that when on collision, the gameobject is not able to stay inside the collider. It gets thrown out when on Collision enter.

Both the collider and the picked up gameobject have rigidbodies because for the picked gameobject the isKinematic is set to true due to the liquid it holds/carries. Therefore for an OnCollisionEnter event to happen one of the colliders should have a non kinematic rigidbody as from the [Unity Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).

I tried changing the project settings from the phyiscs section to Enable contacts and see if the rigidbody maybe the cause, this is after removing a rigidbody from the detect collider but it was still a dead end. This came about from my research using this [forum in unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/collision-detection-for-kinematic-rigidbodies.885778/).

So the question is what should i do to make the gameobject perform the event while inside the collider?
Does the Rigidbodies from the two colliders (picked gameobject and detect) make this not happen?

This is what the object should do on Collision enter!

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("FunnelPour"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Ready To Pour!");
        if (interactor.currentlyPickedUpObject != null)
        {
            interactor.DropObject();
        }

        rb.useGravity = false;

        StartCoroutine(startPour());
    }
}
```

The action or event on how the object should work is under the PourFunnel method.

```
void PourFunnel()
{
    RaycastHit raycastHit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out raycastHit, distanceOfRaycast, detectPour))
    {
        Debug.Log("Pour the beaker to left");
        isPouring = true;
        transform.position = positionToPourLeft;
        rb.constraints &= ~RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis(leftRotationAmount, transform.right), Time.deltaTime * 50);

    }
    else if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.forward, out raycastHit, distanceOfRaycast, detectPour))
    {
        Debug.Log("Pour the beaker to Right");
        isPouring = true;
        transform.position = positionToPourRight;
        rb.constraints &= ~RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis(rightRotationAmount, transform.right), Time.deltaTime * 50);
    }
}

IEnumerator startPour()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);

    Debug.Log("Pour the beaker!");
    PourFunnel();

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToResume);

    Debug.Log("Position the beaker to normal!");
    
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.identity, Time.deltaTime * 100);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
    isPouring = false;
    rb.useGravity = true;
    Debug.Log("Position the Beaker back to where it was picked up!");
    transform.position = positionToDrop;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds a bit like you would want to use the collider as a trigger (tick on IsTrigger) and then use the function [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) in stead of [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).

When two objects hit each other (their colliders enter each other) AND none of the colliders are marked as triggers AND at least one of the objects have a (non-kinematic) RigidBody attached, we will get a 'collision'. This collision will trigger OnCollisionEnter but it will also make Unity's physics engine see this as a physical collision and move the involved non-kinematic RigidBodies according to the collision details. This is why your game object gets 'thrown' away when you collide with it.

If two objects hit each other AND at least one of their colliders is marked as trigger AND at least one of the objects has a RigidBody attached (can be kinematic or not) then the function OnTriggerEnter will be triggered. When one of the involved colliders is marked as trigger, Unity will not see it as a physical collision and they are free to move inside each other without the physics engine kicking in.

Comment: Yeah it works with the ontrigger instead of oncollision enter.